# What is the NULL-like default for OWA_UTIL.ident_arr?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am using PL/SQL within a web application. One of the HTML forms has, among other input elements, a checkbox group:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="included_colors" value="red"> Red</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="included_colors" value="green"> Green</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="included_colors" value="red"> Purple</label>
```

The user may choose

- none of these options, or
- one of these options, or
- multiple options.

The receiving procedure has this "signature", which specifies an [`owa_util.ident_arr`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/portal.1111/e12042/psutil.htm#YPREF425) datatype mapping for the checkboxes:

```
PROCEDURE report(
    included_colors    IN owa_util.ident_arr,  /*<<<<<<< checkboxes */
    region             IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
)
```

If the user checks one or more options, everything works great. *If the user checks none of the options*, Oracle returns this error:

> PLS-00306: WRONG NUMBER OR TYPE OF ARGUMENTS IN CALL TO 'REPORT'

I *could* add a hidden field to the submitting form (ie, `<input type="hidden" name="included_colors" value="ignore_me" />`) to circumvent a NULL-like possibility, but that has some unwanted downstream consequences.

I see that OWA_UTIL.vc_arr can have a default of `null_vc_arr`. **What is the NULL-like default for OWA_UTIL.ident_arr?**

I tried `null_ident_arr`...no joy:

> PLS-00201: identified 'NULL_IDENT_ARR' must be declared

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare a package variable of type `owa_util.ident_arr` and use that as the default value.

```
create or replace package test_array as

  null_ident_arr owa_util.ident_arr;

  procedure report(
      included_colors    IN owa_util.ident_arr default null_ident_arr,  /*<<<<<<< checkboxes */
      region             IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
  );
end test_array;
/
```

Comment: So obvious now that I see it, but my mind was a million miles away from this solution. Thank you, Martin.